# How get a list of all open files in Eclipse editors?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application is editor, almost like in Eclipse. Class editor extends from `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor` and it is added in extension in `plugin.xml -> org.eclipse.ui.editors`. I would like to do view which contains open in editor files. The question is, how do I  get a list of all open files?

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to get it starting from the PlatformUI class.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences()
```

Answer (score -1):

In your workspace the following file contains your workbench information:

.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml
It is possible to delete it (or edit it but that requires some fiddling around I suppose) without breaking your workspace, the file gets regenerated by Eclipse. When you delete it all workbench related settings are lost (ie all editors are closed), but your projects of that workspace stay intact.

from that you can get the list of file..